# Sample 2D grid in Xarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have a 1D array of samples, each having a corresponding x and y coordinate. I want to transform this into a 2D grid where each grid cell contains the average of all samples falling in that grid cell. Of course I could program this by hand, but I've got the impression that this is possible with [multidimensional grouping](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/user-guide/groupby.html#multidimensional-grouping).

As an example data I make a Lissajous curve

[image]

I put this data in a DataArray and make a MultiIndex with `x` and `y` coordinates.

```
my_data = <xarray.DataArray 'my_data' (time: 1200)>
array([0.000e+00, 1.000e+00, 2.000e+00, ..., 1.197e+03, 1.198e+03,
       1.199e+03])
Coordinates:
    h        (time) float64 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 ... 598.0 598.5 599.0 599.5
  * time     (time) object MultiIndex
  * x        (time) float64 0.0 0.3596 0.6711 0.8929 ... 0.5044 0.7812 0.9535
  * y        (time) float64 1.0 0.9498 0.8041 0.5777 ... -0.6339 -0.36 -0.04993
```

The full example code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

DIM_TIME = 'time'

t = np.arange(1200.0)

da = xr.DataArray(
    name='my_data',
    data = t, dims=[DIM_TIME],
    coords = {
        'x': (DIM_TIME, np.sin(t / np.e)),
        'y': (DIM_TIME, np.cos(t / np.pi)),
        'h': (DIM_TIME, t/2)})

da = da.set_xindex(['x', 'y'])  # Add multi index
print(f"\n{da.name} = {da}")

bins = [-1.0, -0.6, -0.2,  0.2, 0.6, 1.0]
binned_x = da.groupby_bins("x", bins).mean().rename("bin_x_avg")
print(f"\n{binned_x.name} = {binned_x}")

da.to_dataset().plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', hue='h')
plt.show()

# Raises IndexError: too many indices
binned_xy = da.groupby_bins(("y", "x"), (bins, bins)).mean() # Something like this.
```

I can group-by one dimension just fine (`binned_x`), it gives a 1D array with 5 elements.

```
bin_x_avg = <xarray.DataArray 'bin_x_avg' (x_bins: 5)>
array([603.20738636, 598.84431138, 600.03870968, 596.18823529,
       597.48876404])
Coordinates:
  * x_bins   (x_bins) object (-1.0, -0.6] (-0.6, -0.2] ... (0.2, 0.6] (0.6, 1.0]
```

I would like to do something similar that bins in two dimensions. It should return a 5 by 5 DataArray. Something like the last statement in my code (`binned_xy`).

Is this somehow possible in XArray?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [flox](https://flox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import flox.xarray


result_raw = flox.xarray.xarray_reduce(
    da,
    da.x,
    da.y,
    func="mean",
    expected_groups=(bins, bins),
    isbin=[True, True],
    method="map-reduce",
)
print(result_raw)

<xarray.DataArray 'my_data' (x_bins: 5, y_bins: 5)>
array([[602.05454545, 610.55769231, 597.79545455, 613.41666667,
        598.03061224],
       [612.52941176, 600.84210526, 562.61538462, 640.25      ,
        586.64705882],
       [582.6744186 , 614.19230769, 630.9375    , 591.19230769,
        602.63636364],
       [601.26923077, 569.52173913, 640.75      , 507.52631579,
        614.73076923],
       [604.28      , 615.91666667, 584.89130435, 593.90740741,
        590.16666667]])
Coordinates:
  * x_bins   (x_bins) object (-1.0, -0.6] (-0.6, -0.2] ... (0.2, 0.6] (0.6, 1.0]
  * y_bins   (y_bins) object (-1.0, -0.6] (-0.6, -0.2] ... (0.2, 0.6] (0.6, 1.0]
```

and if you want numeric coordinates:

```
x_bin_center = [b.mid for b in result.x_bins.values]
y_bin_center = [b.mid for b in result.y_bins.values]

result = result_raw.assign_coords(
    x_bin_center=("x_bins", x_bin_center), y_bin_center=("y_bins", y_bin_center)
).swap_dims(x_bins="x_bin_center", y_bins="y_bin_center")
print(result)

<xarray.DataArray 'my_data' (x_bin_center: 5, y_bin_center: 5)>
array([[602.05454545, 610.55769231, 597.79545455, 613.41666667,
        598.03061224],
       [612.52941176, 600.84210526, 562.61538462, 640.25      ,
        586.64705882],
       [582.6744186 , 614.19230769, 630.9375    , 591.19230769,
        602.63636364],
       [601.26923077, 569.52173913, 640.75      , 507.52631579,
        614.73076923],
       [604.28      , 615.91666667, 584.89130435, 593.90740741,
        590.16666667]])
Coordinates:
    x_bins        (x_bin_center) object (-1.0, -0.6] (-0.6, -0.2] ... (0.6, 1.0]
    y_bins        (y_bin_center) object (-1.0, -0.6] (-0.6, -0.2] ... (0.6, 1.0]
  * x_bin_center  (x_bin_center) float64 -0.8 -0.4 0.0 0.4 0.8
  * y_bin_center  (y_bin_center) float64 -0.8 -0.4 0.0 0.4 0.8
```

Comment: For me the use case is not important enough to take on another dependency, but it is good to know that Flox exists and can do the trick. Thanks for your answer.